# Jetpack update causes Wordpress to report PHP Fatal error - relevance unclear

Tags: php, plugin-jetpack

Upon updating the Jetpack by WordPress.com plugin from v7.7 to v12.5, WordPress v6.3.1 reports the following:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\Jetpack\Roles' not found in /www/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/vendor/automattic/jetpack-sync/src/Listener.php:272"
```

Testing the webpage affected did not show any obvious issues.

What is the relevance of this error and any suggestions on how to deal with it?

Comment: You'll need to ask Jetpack support for help with this, as the plugin is causing the error and third party plugins are off topic.